# How to create the Youtube topics subheaders in Android TV?

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I want to create a subheader rows like the one in Youtube. The subheaders like "Recommended", "Music", "Trending", "Comedy", etc. These are focusable views which also change the underlying fragment.

What is the name of this view and how can I implement it?

[image: Youtube]

Answer (score 0):

You need [Recommending TV Content](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/discovery/recommendations.html).

> The Android TV home screen displays recommendations two different ways
>   depending on which version of Android is running:
>
> - In Android 8.0 (API level 26) and later, apps can show recommendations in one or more channels that appear on seprate rows.
>     One channel (the default channel) always appears. The user can
>     discover and add the other channels to their home screen. Learn how to
>     create [recommendation channels](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/discovery/recommendations-channel.html) on the home screen.
> - Before Android 8.0, Android TV shows all recommendations in a single recommendations row that always appears on the screen. Learn
>     how to create the [recommendation row](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/discovery/recommendations-row.html) on the home screen.

Comment: No. That is for something completely different. Here recommendations is simply the name of a tab.